# In-App purchase with IOS Application

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have developed an `IOS` application, Initially for 15 days I am giving my application for trail period and after 15 days the user have to subscribe the application (They can purchase) to use it uninterruptedly rest of the time , I was planning to use third party payment gateways like (Stripe,Paypal) but I think the Platform like IOS only allowing third party payment gateways for selling physical goods like (Books , Electronics items etc. ) But in our case we just going to sell an upgraded App which is a digital content.My Question is can we sell the App Upgrade features through Stripe payment gateway or any third party payment gateway???
IF not I found the platform `IOS` providing Service API's for `In-App Purchase` inside the App.
So My Question is, Do i need only `In-App purchase` service for selling App in `Appstore`???

Comment: Apple Pay, in-app purchase. basically, that is your safe playground; meanwhile in some cases you can use 3rd party payment to sell physical goods (or collect donations). you may read more about it in the [Apple Review Guideline, section __3. Business__](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments).

Comment: For the scenario you have described, only Apple's in-app purchase can be used.

Comment: @holex Can i use third party payment gateways for selling App upgradation?

Comment: @AbhijitChakra, nope.

Comment: @holex thanks for the conformation if you would have answered i would have accepted it...

Comment: @AbhijitChakra, okay, I did it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

long story short: Apple Pay, in-app purchase (iAP).

basically, that is your safe playground in the scenario which you outlined about your app updates and your digital content briefly.

---

***NOTE***: meanwhile in some cases you may use 3rd party payment to sell physical goods (or collect donations), but in general you may read more about that in the [Apple Review Guideline, section **3. Business**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments).